# Is there any way to send gameobjects over the network? (Mirror)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-mirror

I have a pathfinding script for my 2D multiplayer game (using Mirror) that returns available/walkable tiles in a list. The 'tiles' stored in this list are game objects which are generated over my grid in the scene. I have a function that makes a call to the server in order to move my character with a network transform.. That function checks the index of the list to see which tile to move to (notice path[0] referenced in this function. The index is a game object which is stored in my list of walkable tiles). If I try to use this function I'll get error "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" .. which I've gathered is because my 'tiles' are not actually being sent to the server.

My movement function:

```
   [Command]
 public void CmdMoveAlongPath()
 {   
     var step = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
     var zIndex = path[0].transform.position.z;
     character.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(character.transform.position, 
   path[0].transform.position, step);
     character.transform.position = new Vector3(character.transform.position.x, character.transform.position.y, zIndex);
        if (Vector2.Distance(character.transform.position, path[0].transform.position) < 0.0001f)
        {
            PositionCharacterOnTile(path[0]);
            path.RemoveAt(0);
        } 
 }
```

I call this command from within my Movement script attached to my player.. For further context, startingTile and overlayTile variables shown here are the game objects that I pass to my pathfinding script which is shown here as `pathFinder.FindPath(startingTile, overlayTile);`

CmdMoveAlongPath is executed only when `path.Count > 0`

```
[ClientCallback]
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!hasAuthority) { return; }
     
        var focusedTileHit = GetFocusedOnTile();
        var focusedOnTileFromPlayer = GetFocusedOnTileFromPlayer();

        if (focusedOnTileFromPlayer.HasValue)
        {      
           // Starting tile is the tile detected below player when the scene first loads. 
            startingTile = focusedOnTileFromPlayer.Value.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<OverlayTile>();
         
             startingTile.GetComponent<OverlayTile>().ShowTile();
        }

        if (focusedTileHit.HasValue)
        {
            OverlayTile overlayTile = focusedTileHit.Value.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<OverlayTile>();

            Vector2 touchPostion = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && overlayTile != null) //&& !treeDetected
            {
                

                if (activeTile == null)
                {
                    path = pathFinder.FindPath(startingTile, overlayTile);
                    activeTile = startingTile;
                }

                else 
                {
                    path = pathFinder.FindPath(activeTile, overlayTile);
                } 

            }     

        } 

        if (path.Count > 0)
        {

           CmdMoveAlongPath();
           
        } 

    }
```

My Pathfinding script which calculates the tiles in between the starting tile and selected tile:

```
public class Pathfinder
{
    public List<OverlayTile> FindPath(OverlayTile start, OverlayTile end)
    {
        
        List<OverlayTile> openList = new List<OverlayTile>();
      
        List<OverlayTile> closedList = new List<OverlayTile>();

        openList.Add(start);

        while (openList.Count > 0)
        {

            OverlayTile currentOverlayTile = openList.OrderBy(x => x.F).First();

            if (currentOverlayTile != null) { 
            openList.Remove(currentOverlayTile);
            closedList.Add(currentOverlayTile);

        }

            if (currentOverlayTile == end)
            {
                return GetFinishedList(start, end);
            }

            var neighborTiles = GetNeighborTiles(currentOverlayTile);

            foreach (var neighbor in neighborTiles)
            {
                if (neighbor.isBlocked || closedList.Contains(neighbor) || Mathf.Abs(currentOverlayTile.gridLocation.z - neighbor.gridLocation.z) > 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                neighbor.G = GetManhattanDistance(start, neighbor);
                neighbor.H = GetManhattanDistance(end, neighbor);

                neighbor.previous = currentOverlayTile;

                if (!openList.Contains(neighbor))
                {
                    openList.Add(neighbor);
                }
            }
        }
    
        return new List<OverlayTile>();
    }
```

My OverlayTile class .. I do have a `gridLocation` property on this class. Sending this to the server might be the way to go..

```
public class OverlayTile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int G;
   
    public int H;

    public int F { get { return G + H; } }

    public bool isBlocked;

    public OverlayTile previous;

    public Vector3Int gridLocation; 
   
}
```

From what I've read on other posts, it doesn't seem possible to send game objects like this over the network. But I also haven't found a solid answer on this anywhere yet. Seeing as how my pathfinder needs to check for game objects on the scene, I need to find a way to make this work. Should I just scrap this approach to my pathfinder using game objects?

Comment: Is the client supposed to know where the tile is in the server's memory? This is why structs are generally the only thing allowed to be sent. Just send whatever the server needs to find the tile, then have the server use it to find the tile. That might be a string identifier of the tile, a vector3 to indicate the location, something else, or maybe multiple of them depending on your setup. The question could use a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ruzihm. And correct, my client is able to read which tile I want to move to based off of the index in the list, but my server cannot read in the same format. So it seems that I just need to send the tile position in a different format to my server. I also added a bit more of my code for context, which is where my movement command is being called from the client, and the pathfinding script which adds the start/end tiles to a list

Comment: `gridLocation` or `G` and `H` might be enough. I would start with those

Comment: Awesome. Makes more sense to me now. Thank you for the help

Comment: If you find an answer to this, please consider [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) below as an answer.